# How to create a user and copy corresponding pub file to authorized_key using AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: authentication, ssh, aws-cloudformation

I am having trouble to create a user and copy the corresponding pub file called authorized_keys into the .ssh folder on the instance using AWS Cloud Formation. I do this, because I want to connect with this user using SSH. When I check the SystemLog of the created instance, it does not seem like the user is created or any file is copied as authorized_keys in the .ssh directory,
this is my code:

```
LinuxEC2Instance:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    config:
      users:
        ansible:
          groups:
            - "exampleuser"
          uid: 1
          homeDir: "/home/exampleuser"
      files:
        /home/exampleuser/.ssh/authorized_keys:
          content: !Sub |
            '{{ resolve:secretsmanager:
              arn:aws:secretsmanager:availability-zone:account-id:secret:keyname:
                SecretString:
                  keystring }}'
          mode: "000600"
          owner: "exampleuser"
          group: "exampleuser"
```

Am I missing something so that the user is created and the file is also being copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` you have to explicitly invoke from your `UserData` using [cfn-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) helper script.

An exemple of such a `UserData` for the Amazon Linux 2 is as follows:

```
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe

                yum update -y

                yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v \
                  --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                  --resource LinuxEC2Instance \
                  --region ${AWS::Region}
```

If there are issues, then have to login to the instance and inspect log files such as `/var/logs/cloud-init-output` to look for error messages.

Comment: Hi, so I tried adding above part into my script, however, it does not create any users and I cannot see any cert file being copied if I have a look at the SystemLog using the AWS console. I cannot log into the instance to check the internal logs unfortunately. Any Idea why it does not process the Metadata commands? Do I need to change anything there?

Comment: @Benny You can setup [KeyName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-keyname) in your template to be be able to ssh into it. You can also try [browser based ssh](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-using-amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-access-to-your-ec2-instances/) to inspect the logs in the instance.